# Ionic 3 run function from root page in child page

Tags: ionic3, angular5

Working with Ionic 3.

root page app.component.ts:

```
...
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  sdata = [];
  getListName(){
    //returns an array a list for menu names 
   //sdata
  }
}
```

app.html:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Μενού</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button menuClose ion-item class="menulist elvtitles" *ngFor="let p of sdata" (click)="toElevator(p.elevatorID)">
      <ion-icon name="construct"></ion-icon> {{p.address}}
     </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Now what I want is to run again the function getListName from a page (child). In order my list getting refreshed. Like:

```
export class ChildPage {
  refresh(){
   this.getListName()
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is to use Output method but this below is not working:

```
export class ChildPage {
  @Output() intervalFired = new EventEmitter<any>();  
  refresh(){
     ...
     this.intervalFired.emit(dataAll);
  }
}
```

and in app.html:

```
<child-register (intervalFired)="onIntervalFired($event)"></child-register>
```

or

```
<button (intervalFired)="onIntervalFired($event)" menuClose ion-item class="menulist elvtitles" *ngFor="let p of sdata" (click)="toElevator(p.elevatorID)">
        <ion-icon name="construct"></ion-icon> {{p.address}}
      </button>
```

but nothing is working.

What I need is to call the parent (app.component) function in my child page with some way. 
I guess my problem is clear, if not ask me for details. Any ideas or directions will be appreciated.

Comment: if method should be shared and used by both why not just do shared service and allow both components to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Approaches

1. Create a **Service** and inject or use in your both **App (Parent)** and **Child** Component.
2. Use **Events** (Pub/Sub) Method

Example

**Child Page**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class ChildPage {

    constructor(public events: Events) {}
    ChildPage() {
      console.log('Child Page!')
      this.events.publish('menu:update');
    }
}
```

**App/Parent Page**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp {

    constructor(public events: Events) {
      events.subscribe('menu:update', () => {
         this.getListName()
      });
    }
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  sdata = [];
  getListName(){
    //returns an array a list for menu names 
   //sdata
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer before yours and I did something similar to yours. I didn't test your code but I accept this as correct.

Comment: @VasilisGreece Thanks good to hear is that your problem is resolved